# How to Dock object to parent Window in Java + swt?

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to make "Fluid" layout for Table -view (List view with sortable columns). But I'm only able to set Fixed width and height.

Like in C#, I'm able to define: table.Dock = Dock.Fill;

Does such Behavior exist in Java? I'd want the table to "Dock" into parent window.

Or do I have to make method that loops through all available object on "Window resize" -event and calculate desired width and height?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [Eclipse RPC](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform) and build on top of `ViewPart` class. Also look at [Nebula](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/) project.